# Google+ iOS Sign-In Error "com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher"

Tags: ios, google-api, google-plus

I'm stuck in a very irritating issue for the last 3 days. I have implemented the Google+ sign-in and it worked just fine till I upgraded from G+ iOS SDK version 1.5.1 to 1.7.1. I did exactly like it is mentioned in [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/upgrading-sdk). After when I press the login button, it goes to Safari or Google+ application on the device and switches back to my application with an error which I cannot resolve.

This is how I have implemented,

**StartScreenViewController.h**

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

@interface StartScreenViewController : UIViewController <GPPSignInDelegate> {

    GPPSignIn *signIn;

}
```

**StartScreenViewController.m**

```
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>

static NSString * const kClientId = @"********-*************.apps.googleusercontent.com";

- (void)initUI {

btnGooglePlus = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnGooglePlus addTarget:self action:@selector(loginWithGooglePlus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnGooglePlus];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
    signIn.delegate = self;

}

-(void)loginWithGooglePlus:(id)sender {

[signIn authenticate];

}
```

It switches back to app and calls the delegate method **-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error**

What I'm getting is an error message: **Error Domain=com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GTMHTTPFetcher error -1.)"**

I even implemented the GPPSignInButton and it also gives the same result. I have no idea why it happens. If anyone can point me to the right direction, that will be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. It was not a problem with my coding. Actually it was the [Splunk](https://mint.splunk.com) that was causing all the issues. After integrating splunk, it affect the response that comes from **Google+**. Had to remove and implement [another](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) crash reporting tool solved my issue. Hope this will help to anyone who will come across this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I works with G+ SDK a few days ago and everything was fine. My implementation differs from yours in that I didn't set any scopes and use authentication only after `trySilentAuthentication` like this:

```
-(void)loginWithGooglePlus:(id)sender {
    if (![signIn trySilentAuthentication]) {
         [signIn authenticate];
    }
}
```

You should also try to remove old keychain data via `disconnect`

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I tried all of them. No luck.